# Extrude land in MapBox

Tags: mapbox

I am trying to emphasize the fact that the land is higher than the water in my map so wanted to add an extrusion to the land layer. I thought taking the `https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/` of the one with buildings and changing the layer source to 'land' would work but it didn't. Is this something specific to building layers or am I doing something wrong? Here is my layer definition in my style JSON:

```
    {
        "id": "3d-land",
        "source": "composite",
        "source-layer": "land", # Changed this from building
        "filter": ["==", "extrude", "true"],
        "type": "fill-extrusion",
        "minzoom": 0,
        "paint": {
            "fill-extrusion-color": "#000",
            "fill-extrusion-height":  [
                "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
                15, 0,
                18.0, 30.0
            ],
            "fill-extrusion-base": [
                "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
                15, 0,
                18.0, ["get", "min_height"]
            ],
            "fill-extrusion-opacity": 0.8
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First reason is as the console says, `"land" does not exist on source "composite"`. `"land"` layer is `background` layer which is exist separately in the style. You cannot use `fill-extrusion` for `background` layer. You may want to use layers which use `"compose"` source.

The other reason is from `filter`. `"filter": ["==", "extrude", "true"]` means filtering if the value of layer's property called `"extrude"` is `"true"`. `land` layer doesn't have a property `extrude` so it's always `false`.

So, the result of fix would be looks like:

```js
map.addLayer(
  {
    id: "3d-landcover",
    source: "composite",
    "source-layer": "landcover",
    "type": "fill-extrusion",
    "minzoom": 0,
    "paint": {
      "fill-extrusion-color": "#000",
      "fill-extrusion-height":  [
        "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
        15, 0,
        18.0, 30.0
      ],
      "fill-extrusion-base": [
        "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
        15, 0,
        18.0, ["get", "min_height"]
      ],
      "fill-extrusion-opacity": 0.8
    }
  }
);
```

As the first reason, all the layers except water should be added as above if you want to make the land higher than water. it's not very effective.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like that is the only way then, although it's very viable as you say. A lot of layers would have to extruded to cover all of the land.